# Realm: property declared as origin of linking objects property does not exist

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using Realm Swift for the following code:

```swift
class Item: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var name = ""
    @Persisted(originProperty: "items") var collection: LinkingObjects<SomeCollection>
}

class SomeCollection: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var name = ""
    let items = List<Item>()
}
```

On app startup when I initialize the `Realm` instance I got:

> Property 'SomeCollection.items' declared as origin of linking objects property 'Item.collection' does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Schema validation failed due to the following errors:

Interestingly, if I change the line for `LinkingObjects` to:

```swift
let collection = LinkingObjects(fromType: SomeCollection.self, property: "items")
```

it then works fine, however, after adding an `Item` instance to the `items` list of `SomeCollection`, the `collection` property of `Item` instance doesn't show any linked `SomeCollection`, which I thought should be linked automatically?

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
let items = List<Item>()
```

Needs to be this

```
@Persisted var items = List<Item>()
```

or

```
@Persisted var items: List<Item>
```

depending on the use case.

The `let` syntax is how we used to do it.

That's called and [Inverse Relationship](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/examples/define-a-realm-object-model/#define-an-inverse-relationship-property) and is covered in the documentation a bit further.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me give it a try! The doc doesn't explicitly mention that we have to use the modern way for all properties, so I thought I can mix new and old styles.

Comment: @hzxu Yeah - it's a tad vague for sure! The docs state *Additionally, if you mix `Persisted` and `objc` dynamic property declarations within a class, the `objc` dynamic properties will be ignored* so essentially objects need to be all new style with @Persisted or old style with @objc dynamic.